# Excel Web Access & VSTO

Tags: 2010, excel, excel-services

I created an Excel workbook in Visual Studio 2010 using VSTO, and it fills a table with data retrieved from a WCF service.  The service was added to the project using the standard "Add Service Reference..." method, and it uses the code-behind file to create the service proxy, get the data and then bind it to the table.

This all works fine and dandy when I publish the workbook and run it locally.  However, when I publish it to SharePoint I just get static data.  There are no error messages shown immediately, and I cannot find any errors in the log files.

In order to rule out the service reference as being my main stumbling block, I removed the service code and simply wrote a simple code-behind method to set some static text into a cell - and it still won't run on SP 2010!

Has anyone published a VSTO Workbook to SharePoint 2010 and had the code-behind actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible because code-behind created with VSTO does not execute on the server. Not even VBA will execute on the server! Please see [this post for more details](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/11/19/excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010-feature-support.aspx).